# Column of mixed strings and numbers - need to conditionally convert strings to numerical format

Tags: python, string, numeric

I have a script that processes data from a CSV file, however sometimes one of the columns I am using from the CSV file randomly has some of its numbers enclosed in string characters thus making it a string. In the case it is enclosed in string characters, it is always ="x", i.e., if the number is 0.5, then it is showing as ="0.5" . There are also some files where all numbers display numerically and this is not even an issue.

A column that we will call N might look as such:

```
N

0.15
="0.20"
0.5
="1.25"
="1.55"
2.9
```

and so on. The values not enclosed by the =" " are numeric and obviously the values enclosed are not. I would like the column to display as such, where all values are stored as numeric:

```
N

0.15
0.20
0.5
1.25
1.55
2.9
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.strip` to strip any unwanted strings from the value. For example:

```py
import csv

with open('your_file.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in)
    header = next(reader) # read header
    next(reader) # skip the empty line

    print(header[0])
    print()

    for row in reader:
        print(row[0].strip('="'))
```

Prints:

```
N

0.15
0.20
0.5
1.25
1.55
2.9
```

---

The content of `your_file.csv` was:

```
N

0.15
="0.20"
0.5
="1.25"
="1.55"
2.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this task with the help of pandas library conveniently. Though it might be too much for this task.

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd
import re

# create a function to clean data of a column
def clean_data(x):
    if match := re.search(r'=\"(.*?)\"', x):
        return match.group(1)
    return x

# read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv("testing.csv")

# apply the cleaning function to the column's data.
df['N'] = df['N'].apply(clean_data)

# convert the column to numeric
df['N'] = pd.to_numeric(df['N'])

Output:
0    0.15
1    0.20
2    0.50
3    1.25
4    1.55
5    2.90
Name: N, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You should apply the regex via [`pandas.Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match) rather than `apply`, also that regex's job is equivalent to `.str.slice(start=2, stop=-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the CSV file with the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, then everything you process is text, if you're using [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), then you'll have a mix of string and floats.

With the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```py
with open("filename.csv", "r", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        n_raw = row["N"]
        n = n_raw[2:-2] if n_raw.startswith("=") else n_raw
        print(n)
```

prints

```
0.15
0.2
0.5
1.2
1.5
2.9
```

With pandas (turning everything into floats).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
mask = df["N"].str.startswith("=")
df.loc[mask, "N"] = df.loc[mask, "N"].str.slice(start=2, stop=-2)
df["N"] = pd.to_numeric(df["N"])
```

`df` contains

```
      N
0  0.15
1   0.2
2   0.5
3   1.2
4   1.5
5   2.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the quick responses. In the meanwhile, the following also ended up working for me. I ended up converting everything in the column to strings, then dropping the =" " characters, then converting everything to float.

```
df['N'] = df['N'].astype(str)
df['N'] = df['N'].str.replace('="', '')
df['N'] = df['N'].str.replace('"', '')
df['N'] = df['N'].astype(float)
```